# CSS text-align doesn't work

Tags: html, css

What's wrong with my css: text is not centered as I would expect

see https://jsfiddle.net/L5bgrg8d/

```
  <html>
  <head>
    <title>

    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="header">
        My header
      </div>
      <div id="content">
        <div id="nav"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="footer"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
#header {
  background-color: teal;
  color: white
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: forgot the semicolon after `color: white`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In css you missed semicolon.

```
#header {
  background-color: teal;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: oh thanks I've always been bad at syntax :( will mark your anwser as right one in a few minutes (have to wait)